# Python different Data Interpretation based on second column value

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am working in interpreting and creating data frame of similar header. But not sure how to do that to handle different header on each line.

I have a large text file say abcde.txt

The format of data presented in file,  is like this: (second column value tells about rest of the format and header name is different for different column #2 type.)

```
DATA, 0 , timestamp, (set of 5 numbers(A,B,C,D,E) data repeated multiple times.)
DATA,1 timestamp (set of 4 numbers (AA, BB,CC,DD) repeated  multiple times)
DATA,2, timestamp (set of 3 numbers (AAA, BBB,CCC) repeated multiple times)
DATA, 3 , timestamp (set of 6 numbers repeated multiple times ))
```

Column #2 value goes max 5. And files have multiple lines of same column types.

Example:

```
DATA, 0, A1,B1, C1,D1,E1, A2, B2,C2,D2,E2, A3,B3,C3,D3,D3…
DATA, 1, AA1, BB1,CC1, DD1, AA2, BB2, CC2, DD2, AA3, BB3, CC3, DD3 ….
DATA, 2, AAA1, BBB2,CCC2, AAA1, BBB2,CCC2, AAA1, BBB2,CCC2, AAA1, BBB2,CCC2
DATA, 0, A4,B4, C4,D4,E4, A5, B5,C5,D5,E5, A6,B6,C6,D6,E6…

:::::
```

Edit:

I try to explain little further about question

So I want to make separate data frames to analyse based on  value of second column that could be from 0 to 5.

If you see in example second column has value ==0(line#1) ,  this is 5 header format , so I want to ready 5 values  and make a row in data frame and read next 5 set of values  in the same line and insert row into data frame with repeated timestamp. So if there 10 times repeat of set of 5 value, it would be 10X (5+1(for timestamp)) dimension data frame. And I have to repeat this for all the lines where second column had value ==0 and add it to the data frame to make a complete data frame of second column==0.

```
 Something like this: (this is the data frame where second column value ==0)
Header:             timestamp      A    B   C    D    E 
                    12345          A1   B1  C1   D1   E1
                    12345          A2   B2  C2   D2   E2
                    12345          A3   B3  C3   D3   E3
(new line in file)  14567          A4   B4  C4   D4   E4
                    14567          A5   B5  C5   D5   E5
                    14567          A6   B6  C6   D6   E6
…….
Same with second column value==1 and so on.
I am referring data frame as 2D array.
```

Comment: Sanjay this is pretty confusing to me.  Can you clarify a little more?

Comment: What distinguishes two rows with the same value in the second column?